# Why is Connect() returning a negative value?

Tags: c, sockets, client, client-server

```
#include<io.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<strings.h>

#define MY_PORT     8989 //defining the port for the socket
#define MAXBUF      256



int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    //char str[MAXBUF];
    int a;
    WSADATA wsa;

    SOCKET sockfd , clientfd; //SOCKET is a data type. We initialize two variables of the data type Socket here
    struct sockaddr_in self; //structure for the family,port and IP address of the socket (Socket descriptors)
    char buffer[MAXBUF]; // this is a character array that will receive the message from the client and we will use this to manipulate
    //char message[MAXBUF];
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");


    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0) //WSASTARUP is used to tell windows to get ready for a connection and if it returns a value 0, windows is ready
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }


    printf("Initialised.\n");

    /*---create streaming socket---*/
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 ) //socket is created using a function called socket
                                                        //using AF_INET means that we are using TCP/IP family
                                                          //the if statement here checks whether or not the value returned by the socket is negative or not. If it is negative that means there is some sort of an error
    {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(errno);
    }
        printf("Socket created.\n");
        self.sin_family = AF_INET;
        self.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT);
        self.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        memset(&self,'\0', sizeof(self));
    /*The connect function below is used to establish a connection between the client and the server*/
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&self, sizeof(self)) <0)
        {
        printf("connection with the server failed...\n");
        exit(0);
        }
        else
        printf("connected to the server..\n");

        printf("Please enter message: ");
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof (buffer));
        fgets(buffer, MAXBUF, stdin); //fgets is used here to get whatever is inside the buffer
        while (1)
        {
        /*struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
        int addrlen=sizeof(client_addr);*/

        /*---accept a connection (creating a data pipe)---*/

        a=  write(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if(a<0){
        printf("Error");
            }
        // a= recv(clientfd, buffer, MAXBUF, 0);
        //accept(clientfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addrlen);

        a= read(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if(a<0){
        printf("Error");
      }
        if (strncmp("QUIT", buffer, 4) == 0) {
            printf("Server Exit...\n");
            break;

        }
        }

    close(sockfd); //close the sockfd
    WSACleanup(); // windows socket is cleaned up
    return 0;
}
```

The code works completely fine but for some reason, which I can't wrap my head around the connect function keeps on returning a negative value, or at least a value that is not zero. The server I am using with this client works for other clients, so I know for a fact that there is nothing wrong with it.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect): *"If no error occurs, connect returns zero. Otherwise, it returns SOCKET_ERROR, and a __specific error code can be retrieved by calling WSAGetLastError__."*. So please do yourself a favor and check the details of the error. Either this leads already to an  explanation of your problem or you should at least include these error details in your question.

Comment: The [`connect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect) function returns a "negative" value on error, just as documented.

Comment: move the call to `memset` before setting values in the corresponding structure.

Comment: Also **please** take time to indent your code...

Comment: By using WSAGetLastError, it gave me error code 10049 and also I've moved memset around

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.sin_family = AF_INET;
    self.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT);
    self.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    memset(&self,'\0', sizeof(self));
```

In this code you set all the values of `self` and then you just clear `self` with `memset`. I'm pretty sure that this makes no sense and likely is the cause of the error you see, i.e. no useful parameters given for `connect`.

Even without this erroneous `memset` the code does not make much sense: you are trying to connect to `INADDR_ANY` but there is no such IP address to connect to. `INADDR_ANY` means on the server side to listen on every address of the machine - on the client side it cannot be used but instead the real IP address have to be used, like `127.0.0.1` for localhost.

Comment: Nope, not it, I moved it around still gave me the same error. I think it has something to do with the address, but I'm completely sure

Comment: @user66581: I'm pretty sure that this is at least part of the problem but there might be more problems. As I already said in a comment: get the detailed error using WSAGetLastError to  get more information on why connect failed.

Comment: Yeah I did do that it gave me an error code of 10049, which I feel like has something to do witht the address

Comment: @user66581: I just saw that your code has even more problems, see updated answer.